# How to get the current date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' and 'datetime64[ns]' format?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I am trying to get the current date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, but it seems to be in a `String` format, and I want it to be in `datetime64[ns]` format.

So far, I have done this:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> todays_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

>>> todays_date
    
    '2022-06-06'
```

I have got the current date, but it is not in the format I need.

How do I convert it to `datetime64[ns]`?

Thanks.

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` *is* a string format. `datetime64` is a binary type and has no format. There's no reason to use strings instead of dates. `todays_date` is a string formatted in the way you specified. If you want this to have a different format, specify what you want in `strftime`

Comment: `pd.Series([datetime.today()])`?

Comment: `2022-06-06` is already in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Comment: `pd.Timestamp.now()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert your data to [ns] in pandas this will allow you to achieve the [ns] option

```
todays_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates' : [todays_date]
})
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df.dtypes
```

If for whatever reason you want just the date and not the time for your data you can do this to remove the hours/minutes/seconds and it will still be in [ns] format

```
todays_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates' : [todays_date]
})
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df.dtypes
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.to_datetime("today").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")